# Op Amp Circuit help!

Tags: operational-amplifier, thermocouple

I am hoping you can help me.

I am trying to design an op amp circuit that can read negative 2ma-20ma. We are trying to read a thermocouple and we have tried many variations of a simple circuit design with no luck. Can any one please help. I have attached our current circuit design.

Comment: I don't see the current circuit design?

Comment: You should brief the variations that you've tried

Comment: Is that really the name of the company you work for?

Comment: So, you want an op-amp circuit. The input to the circuit will be 2 to 20 mA of current. What is the output of the op-amp? Are you trying to convert the current to voltage so it can be read by an ADC? If so, please edit your question to make it more clear. Also, there does not seem to be any circuit in your question.

Comment: A thermocouple produces a voltage output - are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: @Andyaka, there are also thermocouples used in furnaces as flame detectors. I don't know much about it, but maybe the OP is talking about that type of thermocouple. I know they are capable of fairly large currents.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you may want to consider redesigning your circuit. If you want to read a Thermocouple, first you need to realise that you need to be reading voltage, not current. This is due to what is called the [Seebeck Effect](https://www.britannica.com/science/Seebeck-effect) And I doubt you would be getting up to 20mA from it.

The easiest way to do this would be first to find the type of Thermocouple you are using. Type K is usually the one most go for, but it depends on your application. You can do a quick google search to tell you the voltage induced by the Thermocouple at different temperatures. A Type K table is [HERE](http://www.intech.co.nz/products/temperature/typek/0to640c.gif). Please note that the voltage is in mV, and that even up at 600°C, it is still only approx 26mV.

The next thing you need to consider is a CJC (Cold Junction Compensation) which will measure the ambient temperature. The reason this needs to be done is because if your Thermocouple is measuring 50°C (for example) in an abmient environment of 25°C, then your reading is going to be approx 70-75°C. Now, it is alot more complicated than that, but that is the simple way of putting it. You need compensation at the cold junction.

Your standard Thermocouple circuit will look like this: 
[image]

TI have an excellent PDF on Thermocouple measurement By the way. It can be found [HERE](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa204/sloa204.pdf).

Now, onto your actual question. Now that you know how Thermocouples work (I hope) you can use an op amp to increase your signal to a readable level for your AtoD then you can program your microcontroller to display your measured temperature. Remember to take into consideration your CJC too.

If you want an example circuit, of a very basic one, have a look at the [LT1025](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1025fb.pdf) which is a CJC compensation chip, which will take care of your cold junction, and it also recommends an op amp which is matched well to it. All you need to do is select your output (whether you want Type K,J,T etc, or possibly in 10mV/°C steps) and voila!

Here is a nice example circuit it provides in the datasheet:
[image]

This circuit works well, I have used it myself.

So, to sum up, Thermocouples work with voltage due to the Seebeck Effect and you can use an op-amp in either a buffer configuration, or inverting/non inverting, depending on your application. And lastly, remember to account for the cold junction!

I hope this will be some use to you. I recommend reading the TI link on Thermocouples before you go any further with your project.

Comment: good answer// Some use chopper op Amps for ultra low DC error since type K are usually ~40uV/'C

Comment: Thank you @TonyStewart.EEsince'75. I believe the op-amp recommended with the LT1025 is a chopper. Although personally, I tend to find Maxim parts to work well for me. They have a good selection of ultra low offset op amps that work very well with Thermocouples.

Comment: The OP may be dealing with a furnace thermocouple. http://home.howstuffworks.com/how-to-repair-gas-furnaces3.htm

Answer (score -2):

Inverting amplifier is perfect current to voltage converter.
A negative current fed into the inverting input (also having a resistor to the output as negative feedback), Non-inverting input grounded.
The output voltage is IxRfb, where I is the applied current, Rfb is the resistance in the negative feedback. The only snag is that 20 mA is a bit too much for most op amps (but not all). You can extend the current handling capability of an op amp by adding say an emitter follower. (NPN base to op amp output, collector to + rail, emitter as output with some pull down resistor to GND. Note that the output will be only positive i.e. no need for complementary (NPN+PNP) follower.